# Flutter BlocBuilder builder gets called only initially and doesn't react to state change

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I've just started with Flutter recently. BLoC does indeed has a steep learning curve...

As it is clear from the title, the BlocBuilder logic gets correctly executed only once, when the app is started. Afterwards, however, UI doesn't get rebuilt on state changes. Although all the events get emitted, and states change.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my 'main.dart':

```
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/authentication_bloc.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/authentication_event.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/authentication_state.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/login/login_bloc.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/signup/signup_page.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/splash_page.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/user_repository.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'auth/login/login_page.dart';

class SimpleBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onCreate(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onCreate(bloc);
    print('onCreate -- ${bloc.runtimeType}');
  }

  @override
  void onEvent(Bloc bloc, Object? event) {
    super.onEvent(bloc, event);
    print('onEvent -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $event');
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print('onTransition -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $transition');
  }

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    print('onChange -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $change');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print('onError -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $error');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }

  @override
  void onClose(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onClose(bloc);
    print('onClose -- ${bloc.runtimeType}');
  }
}

void main() {
  Bloc.observer = SimpleBlocObserver();
  runApp(MyApp(
    userRepository: UserRepository(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserRepository userRepository;

  MyApp({Key? key, required this.userRepository}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;
  UserRepository get userRepository => widget.userRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository);
    authenticationBloc.add(AppStarted());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    authenticationBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => authenticationBloc,
        ),
        BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => LoginBloc(
              userRepository: userRepository,
              authenticationBloc: authenticationBloc),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (BuildContext context, AuthenticationState state) {
            if (state is AuthenticationUninitialized) {
              return SplashPage();
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationAuthenticated) {
              return Dashboard(
                title: 'Dashboard',
              );
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
              return LoginPage(
                userRepository: userRepository,
              );
            }
            if (state is AuthenticationLoading) {
              return LoadingIndicator();
            }
            // else {
            // return Text('Error');
            // }
            return BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is LoginToSignup) {
                  return SignUpPage();
                } else
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const Dashboard({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc =
        BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('logout'),
            onPressed: () {
              authenticationBloc.add(LoggedOut());
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

authentication_bloc

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:co_flutter/auth/authentication_event.dart';
import 'package:co_flutter/auth/authentication_state.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import '../user_repository.dart';

class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  UserRepository userRepository;

  AuthenticationBloc({required this.userRepository})
      : super(AuthenticationUninitialized()) {
    userRepository = UserRepository();
  }

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      final bool hasToken = await userRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();
      await userRepository.persistToken(event.token, event.userId);
      yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
    }

    if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();
      await userRepository.deleteToken();
      yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

authentication_event

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class AuthenticationEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AppStarted extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'AppStarted';
}

class LoggedIn extends AuthenticationEvent {
  final String token;
  final String userId;

  LoggedIn({required this.token, required this.userId});

  @override
  String toString() => 'LoggedIn { token: $token}';
}

class LoggedOut extends AuthenticationEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'LoggedOut';
}
```

authentication_state

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class AuthenticationState extends Equatable {
  const AuthenticationState();
}

class AuthenticationUninitialized extends AuthenticationState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthenticationLoading extends AuthenticationState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthenticationAuthenticated extends AuthenticationState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AuthenticationUnauthenticated extends AuthenticationState {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Comment: Can you try settings the `bloc` parameter in your `BlocBuilder` to `authenticationBloc`?

Comment: Which BlocBuilder does not rebuilds `<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>` or `<LoginBloc, LoginState>`

Comment: @Stijn2210 this doesn't help, I've already tried that before.

Comment: @croxx5f both of them actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here. You already created a bloc:

```
authenticationBloc = AuthenticationBloc(userRepository: userRepository);
```

And here you are trying to create it again.

To fix it replace this code:

```
BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => authenticationBloc,
                ),
```

with this:

```
BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>.value(
          value: authenticationBloc,
        ),
```

Pass bloc into bloc builder

```
BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
 bloc: authenticationBloc,
```

Don't forget to dispose bloc authenticationBloc after you used it in dispose function.